# IntellJ and WSL2 groovy console freeze

Tags: intellij-14, groovy-console

I'm trying to use intellij  groovy console to test out some scripts.  I have install groovy both on my windows machine and inside of WSL2  with sdk command.

I have restarted my machine but everytime I try to run the groovy console.  IntelliJ freezes up.  looking in the logs of intelliJ I see

```
2023-05-15 16:21:09,736 [ 404917]   WARN - #o.j.p.g.c.GroovyConsole - Cannot run program "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\lib\jvm\java-17-openjdk-amd64\bin\java" (in directory "removed"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\lib\jvm\java-17-openjdk-amd64\bin\java" (in directory "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\pathremoved"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:356)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.startProcess(OSProcessHandler.java:84)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:44)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.KillableProcessHandler.<init>(KillableProcessHandler.java:41)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ColoredProcessHandler.<init>(ColoredProcessHandler.java:23)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole$3.<init>(GroovyConsole.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole.createProcessHandler(GroovyConsole.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole.createConsole(GroovyConsole.java:147)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole.lambda$getOrCreateConsole$1(GroovyConsole.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole.lambda$getOrCreateConsole$2(GroovyConsole.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.util.ModuleChooserUtil.selectModule(moduleChooserUtil.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsoleUtil.selectModuleAndRun(GroovyConsoleUtil.java:26)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.console.GroovyConsole.getOrCreateConsole(GroovyConsole.java:137)
```

I did see in the groovy console  it has listed version 4.0.5, so I got that version in my wsl2 with sdk but has not changed anything for me.

Comment: same problem here, do you find any workaround ?

Comment: Sadly I did not find a workaround